# Python Requests: Multipart with one part as json

Tags: python, json, python-requests, multipartform-data

Netflix's Genie API either takes [JSON](https://netflix.github.io/genie/docs/3.3.9/rest/#_api_docs) or [multipart](https://netflix.github.io/genie/docs/3.3.9/rest/#_api_docs_2) with one part `request` in `application/json` and any number of `attachment` parts in `application/octet-stream`.

Requests makes a plain JSON POST pretty simple:

```py
requests.post(
  url=self.host + self.endpoint,
  json={
    "version" : "1.0",
    "user" : "genie",
    "name" : "List * ... Directories bash job",
    "description" : "Genie 3 Test Job",
    "configs" : [ "/home/travis/build/Netflix/genie/genie-web/build/resources/test/com/netflix/genie/web/controllers/JobRestControllerIntegrationTests/job/config1" ],
    "dependencies" : [ "/home/travis/build/Netflix/genie/genie-web/build/resources/test/com/netflix/genie/web/controllers/JobRestControllerIntegrationTests/job/dep1" ],
    "setupFile" : "/home/travis/build/Netflix/genie/genie-web/build/resources/test/com/netflix/genie/web/controllers/JobRestControllerIntegrationTests/job/jobsetupfile",
    "commandArgs" : "-c 'echo hello world'",
    "clusterCriterias" : [ {
      "tags" : [ "localhost" ]
    } ],
    "commandCriteria" : [ "bash" ],
  },
)
```

The command is limited so if you have a big command (query) to send, you'd best use an attachment.

With requests it isn't that hard to request multipart either:

```py
requests.post(
  url=self.host + self.endpoint,
  json={
    "version" : "1.0",
    "user" : "genie",
    "name" : "List * ... Directories bash job",
    "description" : "Genie 3 Test Job",
    "configs" : [ "/home/travis/build/Netflix/genie/genie-web/build/resources/test/com/netflix/genie/web/controllers/JobRestControllerIntegrationTests/job/config1" ],
    "dependencies" : [ "/home/travis/build/Netflix/genie/genie-web/build/resources/test/com/netflix/genie/web/controllers/JobRestControllerIntegrationTests/job/dep1" ],
    "setupFile" : "/home/travis/build/Netflix/genie/genie-web/build/resources/test/com/netflix/genie/web/controllers/JobRestControllerIntegrationTests/job/jobsetupfile",
    "commandArgs" : "-c 'cat query.sql'",
    "clusterCriterias" : [ {
      "tags" : [ "localhost" ]
    } ],
    "commandCriteria" : [ "bash" ],
  },
  files={
    "attachment": (
      'query.sql',
      'select count(1) from small_table;',
      'application/octet-stream'
    ),
  },
)
```

Except, if `files` exists it'll ignore `json` an if I change `json` to `data` it'll be a form. I could move the JSON dict into the `files` dict but it doesn't seem to get handled as JSON, and now I need to use the package to encode it?

I ask because with `requests` handling json in the argument and response object I suspect it would handle it somewhere for the multipart form too, otherwise I'm bringing in `json` just for `json.dumps(...)`

Additionally:

1. There doesn't seem to be a way to send more than one part named `attachment` which the api would allow/expect if you need more than one attached file. [As in my comment, this can be done by changing `files` to a list of list name-to-file pairs].
2. The example requests show part headers have names which are unquoted like `Content-Disposition: form-data; name=request` and `Content-Disposition: form-data; name=attachment` while the request package seems to generate `Content-Disposition: form-data; name="attachment"` instead.

Comment: I mean I know I can wrap the dict in `json.dumps(…)`, but `requests` has done such a nice job with handling it with the `json=` argument and the `.json()` response method, am I missing some way that it supports this for json parts in a multipart form?
And for #1, it seems if I use a list of lists for files instead of a dict, I can have multiple `[['attachment',('a','content','plain/text')],['attachment',('b','content','plain/text')]]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"I could move the JSON dict into the files dict but it doesn't seem to get handled as JSON"

> 1. You can dump the dict to JSON files on disk.
>
> [`tempfile.TemporaryFile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.TemporaryFile) can of use. *Dump, request, clean and repeat*

"otherwise I'm bringing in json just for json.dumps(...)"

> 2. It is okay to do this if you need to keep the dict around and the request built during run (ignore 1 for this use-case). However, remember to convert the dumps to io.BytesIO objects so that requests can compute the content-length header.
>
> Also, remember to pass the content type for the files as "application/octet-stream" and not "plain/text"

"The example requests show part headers have names which are unquoted"

> I don't think that it should matter. [RFC 2183](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2183) documents that parameter values of length < 78 but containing tspecials [should](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2119) be represented as quoted-string.
>
> While the value for the name parameter doesn't include tspecials, this is more robust handling for short values IMO.

Comment: Thanks for the clarifications; I did change the content type but will need to wrap it as bytes somewhere.
So I'm guessing I'm not missing an idiomatic way to include the json without specifically dumping it to json.